# How to move files from recursive hidden folder to the parent folder on OS X

Tags: macos, bash

I have a music directory 5 level deep, each folder have music and image files and also a hidden sub folder named .unwanted, I want to move the hidden files from folders named .unwanted, up one level to its respective parent folder and if the file name already exist then giving sequential name. Its 90 gb, 9,000 music files and impossible to do it manually..I am newbies to bash, what I did i copy and past some code while changing the folder name only. Its look like that,

$ find . -ipath ".unwanted/.*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(dirname "{}")"/..'

But received errors 'no such directory

[structure of Dir A.]

Comment: i suggest you to edit your question cause is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what you want. You must have the absolute path to the music folder in the find command. Do not use a dot. The -n option in mv is non-standard but will prevent overwriting files.

```
    find /absolute/path/to/music/folder -type d -name ".unwanted" -exec ksh -c 'cd "{}"; mv -n ./* ../' \;
```

Comment: I drag n drop the 'A' folder which is the music folder to the terminal.            $ find /Volumes/BUP\ 1/Music/Music/A\ -type d -name ".unwanted" -exec ksh -c 'cd {}; mv -n ./* ../' \;
    received the following errors       find: /Volumes/BUP 1/Music/Music/A -type: No such file or directory
find: d: No such file or directory                                                                                      its not seems to work, i dont know what i did wrong.

Comment: It look like there is a space after the A in the directory A. Select the directory in the Finder application and remove the trailing space. If any other files/directories have a trailing space in there names then my proposal will fail.

Comment: you are right, fixed it and also move the dir from exfat to mac os extended partition, will give it a try tomorrow. Thank you so much, I sure tomorrow its will work out, (said Scarlet).:)

Comment: the script finally run , however its move every folder  in the directory  up one level so the parent folder become sister folder, but it did not move the hidden files from the hidden _.unwanted_  sub folder  up one level to its parent folder.

Comment: I have no idea what a "sister" folder is and I cannot reproduce your results. But I did find an issue with the original command and  I added quotes around the curly braces in case directory names contained spaces. I did test my proposal and the command does move files from a .unwanted directory to the parent directory of  the .unwanted directory (up one level). It does not move files in the .unwanted directory if a file in the parent directory has the same name.

Comment: sister meant after the run the s.folders move up one level to be same level as its parent folder. much appreciate your help. will  give it a try.